# Spring boot Could not resolve placeholder

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin, spring-boot-test

I have a problem, when I start my spring boot tests from IDE, everything work well, but if I start tests from command line (mvn clean unstall) I have error 
Could not resolve placeholder 'raster.executor.pool.max' in value "${raster.executor.pool.max}"

My test class have annotation @ActiveProfiles("test"), and I have resorces file with description every values

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner::class)
@SpringBootTest
@ActiveProfiles("test")
abstract class AbstractIntegrationTest {
...
}
```

aloso I added plugin in pom.xml

```
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <argLine>-Dspring.profiles.active=test</argLine>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
```

I use spring boot 2.3.0.RELEASE and Kotlin 1.3.72.
Property 'raster.executor.pool.max'  contains in src/main/resources/application-test.properties

Comment: have you set the property `raster.executor.pool.max` in environment variable settings in IDE?

Comment: No, bacase it already seted

Comment: can you please add one example of a concrete integration test and the content of `application-test.properties`