# Could not resolve placeholder in jar file

Tags: java, spring-boot, jar

I faced the problem that during execution of my Spring Boot app in IntelliJ IDEA (Java) all works fine. But when I created jar file and tried to run the app in console, I have UnsatisfiedDependencyException because could not resolve placeholder.

Detailed description of Exception is below:
`WARN org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext - Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'controllerBattle': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'controllerMarket'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'controllerMarketBean': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'meteorRain'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'meteorRainBean': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'priceMeteorRain' in value "${priceMeteorRain}"`

I researched this problem and found similar problem raised 2 years ago:
[Spring boot Could not resolve placeholder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62296538/spring-boot-could-not-resolve-placeholder)

But it was related to kotlin and it was left unsolved.

Are there ways to solve this problem for Java?

I'll be grateful for your help.

Comment: "UnsatisfiedDependencyException because could not resolve placeholder". I honestly do not see a link between these two

Comment: @Stultuske I added detailed description of exception above

Comment: you have posted a WARNING, not an exception. Either way, in your properties (the right one), you need to add a property with this key: priceMeteorRain, and set a value. That's what it's complaining about

Comment: @Stultuske My property file already has the key priceMeteorRain. If it was missed, there would have been error during execution in IntelliJ IDEA but the execution is correct.

Comment: apparently you added it in the wrong property/yaml/... file. your error message is quite specific: that placeholder isn't found in your properties